# QuerySelector search for style and parameters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2

How can i search for this:

```
<div class="tp-backdrop tp-active" style="z-index: 300000; display: block; height: 100%;"></div>
```

I want search by **style** with **display: block** parameters 
I tried:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll("div[style=display: block]");
```

It didn't work.

Comment: solution: 
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('div[style*="display: block"]')

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question here.

Comment: Note it will only return elements which have inline `style` and that inline `style` contains the string `display: block`. It won't find the ones which contain `display:block` (the space is missing), nor will it find all the block elements in the page (the ones which have a computed style of `display` value set to `block`, regardless of where the value is coming from).

Comment: Is this *really* the only way you can use to target the element you require? It's a very brittle way to do it. If you have control of the HTML I'd strongly suggest you amend it to use a class, or select based on parent elements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('div[style*="display: block"]')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I'll give it a go, since I had to find it myself.

The * operator will match the value(after = ) anywhere in the style attribute of a element.
For other operators, you can see them here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors